# Aligning elements on top of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a design I am trying to replicate but I am having issues aligning some items and was wondering what the best way to do this would be because I want to try and avoid absolute positioning if possible.

The design looks like the following [image]

[image]

So they grey area is a section.  What I envisioned was a row containing three `col-md-4` columns.  Within the first column I have some text which should be vertically aligned in the middle.  So I have the following

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it only seems to align it vertically in the middle if I apply it to the whole section, and this makes the other columns have their content vertically aligned, which I don't want.  So I need to somehow only make this vertically aligned.

Second column is pretty straight forward, just a single image.

Where I am having an issue is with column 3, and the two rectangles partly in column one and column 2.  I presume I have to use absolute positioning for this?  Will this impact it in terms of responsiveness?

The second issue is that the grey area is set to `100vh`.  However, some of these rectaingles go out of this area and because they are absolutely positioned, they do not push the content down.

I have reproduced a fiddle which should demonstrate my issues, you may need to expand the preview area [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/2/)

Any advice on how I could achieve this type of layout would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should add your full code in the question itself. Also, you're fiddle doesn't reproduce the entire problem you're describing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the question with something hopefully more relevant.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your desired layout is for this.

Comment: Appologies. I have added another image which hopefully shows it better.  This is basically a section.  I placeholders are where images should be placed.  Thanks

Comment: I think it is a bit awkward to understand because you have elements which seem to go across columns and ordinarily you have columns to avoid this. To vertically aligned the elements without using absolute positioning or display: inline-block I think you could use flexbox and justify-content: center;

Comment: @kate_hudson do you aim at creating a responsive design as well??

Comment: Hi, it will also be responsive which is why I am reluctant to use absolute positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1
Vertically align the content in column one to center.

This is an update to your layout which has centrally aligned your first column.

https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/5/

To summarize I have added few classes at right places

```
<section class="row my-section-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 my-section-row-description">
            <div class="my-section-row-description-body">
```

And I have added this CSS

```
.my-section-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.my-section-row-description {
  display: flex;
}

.my-section-row-description-body {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Now images

First of all the container should have padding bottom. The value should be in `px` as its totally dependent on height of images which are vertically overflowing and which is random.

Column 1 and Column 3 should be position `relative` and all images inside them should be position absolute. Try to convert all `top` and `left` values to `percent` and also `width` to `percent`. Set its `bottom` property to align it from bottom if required.

The image which overlaps column 1 and column 2 should not be in any column and instead should be inside `.container` or `.row` with position `absolute`. Its immediate parent should be position `relative`.
You can use left as `33%` and set `translateX` to `-50%`. that would put it right between column 1 and 2 assuming column 1 and 2 are of same width. Set its `bottom` property to align it from bottom if required.

Hope that makes sense.

UPDATE

To make you understand better consider this image

[image: box model]

`.container` has a `margin` and a `padding-bottom`

`.container` and `.column-3` will have relative position

Image boxes will have absolute position. They are color coded to represent their position in DOM.

Also I think you should [read more](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) about `relative` and `absolute` positioning.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to position the images, every time I try it gets covered by the next section, it doesnt push the current section down